# Value must consist of lowercase alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to check the value

Value must consist of lowercase alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character

```
const regularExpressionTemplate = /^[a-z\d]+(?:[a-z-0-9.-]+)+$/;
const result = regularExpressionTemplate.test(value);
```

This regex works fine, but it is true if I input two or more characters, but I need this work even with one character

How can I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: `/^[a-z\d][a-z\d.-]*[a-z\d]$/`?

Comment: @trincot this asks two or more characters/digits too

Comment: That is what you asked for in one of the first versions of your question, but since then you have updated it quite a few times... I didn't follow.

Comment: `/^[a-z\d]([a-z\d.-]*[a-z\d])?$/` with optional part.

Comment: @trincot I just rephrased the question, sorry

Comment: @trincot, thank you very much for your reply, the latest works great!

Answer (score 1):

This regex requires an alphanumeric character at the front. And also allows any number of alphanumeric characters, dots, or dashs in the middle so long as it is followed by an alphanumeric character.

```js
const regularExpressionTemplate = /^[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9\.\-]*[a-z0-9])?$/;
const values = [
  'test',
  't-t',
  't-2',
  't2',
  't',
  '3',
  't@t',
  '@'
];
const result = values.map(value => regularExpressionTemplate.test(value));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, yeah, that works fine too, but it also requires two or more characters/digits

Comment: I updated the response based on your updated question.